# Connect JPA eclipselink to mlab

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, eclipselink, persistence

Hi guys I have a big problem: I developed my webservice with eclipselink JPA + mongoDb, everything works fine on my local machine but when I try to set the persistence.xml for the connection to a remote NoSql Database it doesn't work.

Here's my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="introsde-final-jpa">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>

            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoPlatform"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.connection-spec" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoConnectionSpec"/>

            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.host" value=<my_host>/>
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.port" value=<my_port>/>
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.db" value="mydb"/>       
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.user" value=<my_user>/>       
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.password" value=<my_password>/>       

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

any suggestion is appreciated!!

Comment: Is there an error or something that helps narrow down the potential problem?  Turn Eclipselink logging on to get more detail.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for your interest. The ony error Eclipse shows is the "login failed" one

Comment: If it is an EclipseLink error, it will contain a stack trace that shows the internal exception and error message that tells you what went wrong.